# Python не может импортировать класс из внешней библиотеки

Tags: python, xls

Пытаюсь запустить пример библиотеки для работы с xlsx.При запуске скрипта выдаёт

> ImportError: cannot import name
> Workbook

Класс должен быть с большой буквы(Pycharm подсказывает как его правильно написать),местоположение плагина добавил в path как советовали на stackoverflow.Всё равно не хочет запускаться.P.S. на Linux системе запускалось без проблем. Как обойти это?Заранее спасибо!

```
from xlsx import Workbook

class XLSXQlik:
    #nameXLSX = "The file not found!"
    def readXLSX(self,nameXLSX):
        book = Workbook(nameXLSX)
        for sheet in book:
            print sheet.name
            for row, cells in sheet.rows().iteritems(): # or sheet.cols()
                print row # prints row number
                for cell in cells:
                    print cell.id, cell.value, cell.formula

#Usage reader class
importXlSX = XLSXQlik()
importXlSX.readXLSX('input.xls')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

мелочный косяк....Файл назывался мой так же,как и библиотека.Он пытался не из библиотеки взять файл,а из файла.Ох уж этот питончик

Comment: Причем тут "питончик"?)

Comment: ну логичнее было бы при импорте из файла применять допустим его расширение,чтобы было понятно,что ты к файлу стукаешься а не к библиотеке